# read Proviso raw BOF Files using python

Tags: python, networking, automation, audit, transmitfile

Sample of BOF files for raw data

Metric ID ( KPI ID) 11119

subelement ID 202264922

Command to get data from BOF files

#bofDump -m 11119 -r 202264922 filepath  .BOF

Proviso it is a tool from ibm, used for service audit and control under category of tnpm, it has a utility called bofDump, which function is explained at the command line above, ex
bofDump -m 2209 -r 202330690 1.00.00.001.All-gIi.NRAW.BOF,
Output >>>
[6146],  (Mid) 2209, (Rid) 202330690, (EventId) 0, (PollId) 0, (date) [1696309201], 2023.10.03-05.00.01, (Val) 6.6781230528245d6

[9286],  (Mid) 2209, (Rid) 202330690, (EventId) 0, (PollId) 0, (date) [1696309201], 2023.10.03-05.00.01, (Val) 6.6778907224569d6

I need to simulate what bofDump does using python

[sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaBhb.png)

I tried using the following code,
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF2YT.png)

And resulted in:

[4294901759], (Mid) 1314013527, (Rid) 808726579, (EventId) 1314013527, (PollId) 20, (date) [47755942339360], 1971.07.07-17.32.22, (Val) 1.1383655345453332e+179d
[0], (Mid) 117964800, (Rid) 728697850, (EventId) 2831115548, (PollId) 395591769, (date) [1800], 1970.01.01-00.00.00, (Val) 2.3594570484718e-310d
[1696339860], (Mid) 1079574528, (Rid) 0, (EventId) 117964800, (PollId) 728697850, (date) [6119658639995453529], Invalid Timestamp, (Val) 8.893e-321d
[11119], (Mid) 200954054, (Rid) 1696339860, (EventId) 1079574528, (PollId) 0, (date) [506654958807878650], Invalid Timestamp, (Val) 3.0495005986676616e+85d
[0], (Mid) 1800, (Rid) 11119, (EventId) 200953657, (PollId) 1696339861, (date) [4636737291354636288], Invalid Timestamp, (Val) 8.664933938828414e-275d

which should have been liek that
[1],  (Mid) 2208, (Rid) 200953269, (EventId) 0, (PollId) 0, (date) [1696309200], 2023.10.03-05.00.00, (Val) 3.1702319448818d7
[2],  (Mid) 2209, (Rid) 200953269, (EventId) 0, (PollId) 0, (date) [1696309200], 2023.10.03-05.00.00, (Val) 4.2390796397657d6
[3],  (Mid) 2211, (Rid) 200953269, (EventId) 0, (PollId) 0, (date) [1696309200], 2023.10.03-05.00.00, (Val) 6.36036808d8
[4],  (Mid) 2210, (Rid) 200953269, (EventId) 0, (PollId) 0, (date) [1696309200], 2023.10.03-05.00.00, (Val) 4.756655638d9
[5],  (Mid) 2208, (Rid) 200976052, (EventId) 0, (PollId) 0, (date) [1696309200], 2023.10.03-05.00.00, (Val) 7.019752009797d6

I believe the solution is about format string used in the code, as i don't know how data has been encoded, or how bofDump works.